# Services not synchronized Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, service, propagation

I'm currently facing an issue which I'm unable to solve.

Here the problem.
I have a class **Picker** inside **Microservice PickerManager** that requires services. This **Picker** class sends events via RabbitMQ to **Microservice B**.

```java
@Component
class Picker {
    @Autowired
    public Picker(Services services,
                  ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher,
                  UtilsPickerManager utilsPickerManager,
                  UtilsAW utilsAW) throws Exception {
        this.services = services;
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
    }
    private PickerCommandEO movePickerToTargetSegment() {
        // ... code
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(commands.get(0).getEvent()); // <- Send an event
        // ... code
    }
}
```

Sending this event invokes the following method:

```java
@Component
public class DriverCommandSenderImpl {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DriverCommandSenderImpl.class);
    private final String exchangeName;
    private final AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;
    DriverCommandSenderImpl(@Value("${corren.driver.pickers.commands.exchange-name}") String exchangeName, AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
        this.exchangeName = exchangeName;
        this.amqpTemplate = amqpTemplate;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onPickerCommand(PickerCommand mo) {
        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        String moAsString = gson.toJson(mo);
        try {
            amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(exchangeName, "csa.commands."+mo.getType(), moAsString); //<- Send Event to Microservice B
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new TechnicalRuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, the event is sent to **Microservice B**. The **Microservice B** responds with another event to the **PickerManager microservice** once the message processing has been completed. This message arrives in the Picker's queue.

```java
@TxService
public class ListenerConfiguration {
    private final AcknowledgmentHandler acknowledgmentHandler;
    private final Services services;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ListenerConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    public ListenerConfiguration(
        AcknowledgmentHandler acknowledgmentHandler,
        Services services
    ) {
        this.acknowledgmentHandler = acknowledgmentHandler;
        this.services = services;
    }

    // The queue is triggered when a new message is received.
    @RabbitListener(queues = "${corren.driver.pickers.acknowledgements.queue-name}")
    public void receiveAcknowledgmentCommand(String message) throws Exception {
        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        AcknowledgementMO acknowledgementMO = gson.fromJson(message, AcknowledgementMO.class);
        acknowledgmentHandler.handler(acknowledgementMO);
    }
}
```

Well. Now, I let's save a Picker inside DB. For doing that I'm using the following method inside **Picker class**

```java
@Component
class Picker {
    @Autowired
    public Picker(Services services,
                  ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher,
                  UtilsPickerManager utilsPickerManager,
                  UtilsAW utilsAW) throws Exception {
        this.services = services;
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
    }
    public void savePicker() {
      PickerEO picker = new PickerEO();
      services.getPickerManager().save(pickerEO);
    }
}
```

Alright. Now, I'm checking if Picker exist in DB from the **services** contained inside the **Picker** class. And, yes ! It well exist. Great.
[image]

What is really really weired now. I want to check from the class **ListenerConfiguration** through the service attribute (which is @Autowired also) if the **Picker** exist in DB. And... Guess what. No! The picker value is not inside the results.

[image]

We are agree to say that is not normal at all because the both service inside the both class have been injected by using the @Autowired decorator. So it's should be the same instance of the object. Of course I've check that. Inside the both class, the service attribute have the same ID value. So it confirm that it's the same object.

Screen of the service ID from **Picker** class
[image]

Screen of the service ID from **ListenerConfiguration** class
[image]

I'm blocked at that point.

If someone have an idea. Thank you for your time.